# Query with three(or more) many-to-many related entities in ef code first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using EF5.0 in .net4.0 and I have Three entity with many-to-many relatinships like this :

```
    public class A
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
    }
    public class B
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ICollection<A> As { get; set; }
        public ICollection<C> Cs { get; set; }
    }
    public class C
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is my mapping code:

```
        HasMany(a => a.Bs).WithMany(b => b.As).Map(m =>
        {
            m.ToTable("A_B");
        });

        HasMany(c => c.Bs).WithMany(b => b.Cs).Map(m =>
        {
            m.ToTable("B_C");
        });
```

For a certain instance of A,how could I get all the Cs which  related indirectly by B?

I want to get a clean sql query like:

```
select C.* from C 
join B_C on B_C.Cid = C.id
join A_B on A_B.Bid = B_C.Bid
join A on A.id = A_B.Aid
where A.id = 1
```

Coude I got that sql without given the junction table an entity type?
My code below got a pretty ugly sql with nested query:

```
var res = Context.C.Where(
                 c => c.Bs.SelectMany(b => b.As.Select(a => a.Id))
                          .Contains(theA.Id)
                     );
```

Please help me with this,thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would try this query:

```
var res = Context.C.Where(c => c.Bs.Any(b => b.As.Any(a => a.Id == theA.Id)));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but this query make the sql more complicated than mine...it will generate one more nested query and one more ‘exist’.